# Can you go back to the last iteration of Google Image search?

Tags: google-image-search

For a long time, when you clicked an image from the search results on Google Image search, it would slide out a new page section and expand the image to fill it most of it, alongside a batch of related images in thumbnails on the right side. You could press left and right arrow keys to move through different images in the search results once one was expanded this way.

But now when I click one, it takes me to the webpage the image came from, within an iframe or something, with a google bar at right and the image superimposed over the greyed-out page in the background. You can click the page to be taken there directly.

I *really* don't like this new functionality. Is there any way to get back to how it was?

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing. When I click an image, the page gets split with a larger version of the image, some buttons ("Visit page", "View image", etc.), arrows to move the next or previous image, and a set of related images. Essentially, what you say it's no longer doing for you. What browser are you using? What OS? Have you tried using a browser without any add-ons active?

Comment: Chrome, Windows 7, still happens with all extensions disabled, from Paris. Happened from the US before I left, too.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to tell you, then. Unless France is preventing some functionality from Google (which actually wouldn't surprise me) I'm seeing it act the way you expect.